# How to use HttpClient GET method in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

First of all sorry for my bad English. I'm newbie with Angular.
My website consume an asp.net core Api.
I try to log user.
My user interface is :

```
  export interface iuser{
    username: string;
    login: string;
    password: string;
    roles: string[];
  }
```

I also have an AuthService with this function:

```
  SignIn(login: string, password : string): Observable<iuser> {
    let apiUserAccount: string = environment.apiAddress + 'UserAccount/' + 'Login?' + 'login=' + login + '&' + 'password=' + password;
    return this.http.get<iuser>(apiUserAccount);
  }
```

And in my component I call this function service like this:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }
    this.loading = true;
    this.AuthService.SignIn(this.f.login.value, this.f.password.value)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.user = response as iuser
        console.log('User = ' + this.user.username);
      });
      if(this.user == null){
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
  }
```

User is declared upper like this :

```
 user!: iuser;
```

My api service is called and returns the user, but the property user in Angular project is always 'undefined'. I don't understand why?

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: `if(this.user == null)` move this check inside of the `.subscribe` block as this code would be run before a response is returned from the server otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the user right after the http call. As it's async it's value won't be set right away. You have to move the router navigation in the subscription too, but I would suggest you using the [finalize operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize). It's called when the call completes or errors.

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  // You should always negate the `valid` property, as when the `FormGroup` is in `"DISABLED"` state, both `valid` and `invalid` properties are set to `false`;
  // Or you can check with `this.loginForm.state === 'VALID'`.
  if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
    return;
  }
  this.loading = true;
  this.AuthService.SignIn(this.f.login.value, this.f.password.value)
// Use the finalize operator
    .pipe(finalize(() => {
      this.loading = false;
      if(this.user == null){
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
     }))
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.user = response as iuser; 
      console.log('User = ' + this.user.username);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a problem with finalize => "not found" Edit: sorry I had not seen the link

Comment: You should import it. `import { finalize } from "rxjs/operators";`

Comment: @Totali Same result user is undefined

Comment: Hmmm. Are you sure your api returns the user? What does `console.log(response)` write on the console? (write it right after the subscribe `.subscribe(response => { *here*`

Comment: @Totali yes reponse contains user description

Comment: Is it possible that Angular user interface must have same properties that user api class?

Comment: No, you could assign `this.user = {} as isuer`; and it must not navigate away.

Comment: Could you post your form too?!

Comment: @Totali I don't understand this : this.user = {} as isuer;

Answer (score 0):

I had displayed user value before assign response to user like this:

```
console.log('User = ' + this.user);
this.user = response as iuser;
```

I think user is no more undefined know.
I will try to display values in html part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my form

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <div class="login-form bg-light mt-4 p-4">
                <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="row
                    g-3">

                    <span class="fw-bold text-secondary d-flex align-items-center">
                        <i class="bi-geo-alt-fill color-primary"></i>
                    </span>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand color-secondary">Food<b class="color-primary">Truck</b></a>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="login" formControlName="login" class="form-control" placeholder="login"
                            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.login.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.login.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.login.errors.required">Login is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password"
                            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="rememberMe">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="rememberMe">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Alert -->
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="submitted && (error)">
                            Login ou Mot de passe incorecte
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <hr class="mt-4">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p class="text-center mb-0">Pas encore de compte? <a
                            href="#">Signup</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try know to display user informations on html page.
So I send user values to my AuthService like below.
[onSubmit function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnIki.jpg)

And I added in my AuthService a function to get user name like this:[getLoggedUser function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vkxP.jpg)

As you kan see if I test this.loggedUser in debbug console it returns values. But when I call getLoggedUser function in a html page like this:

```
<h1>User : {{authService.getLoggedUser()}}</h1>
```

I haven't values.

How is that possible?